# How to clear repository checkout history in Xcode

Tags: xcode, git, repository, git-checkout

As shown in the snapshot below [image], how to clear these history items? I already deleted Preferences > Accounts > Repositories, but these still in check out history.

Comment: Wondering about this as wel