# how to remove repository checkout history in xcode?

Tags: xcode, repository, checkout, history

[image: image for question]

As shown in the picture, how to clear? I tried to remove at xcode->preference->acount, but it had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal hit below command to clear the XCode preferences

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works on maOS 10.11.6 Xcode 7.3.1 (other versions may store the list differently/elsewhere, I think Xcode 11 and perhaps earlier can remove items directly from the GUI):

One can also use `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy` to remove individual repositories.

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist

print :IDESourceControlRecentsFavoritesRepositoriesUserDefaultsKey
```

count the top level items you want to delete (0-based), for instance to remove the second one:

```
delete :IDESourceControlRecentsFavoritesRepositoriesUserDefaultsKey:1
```

rinse and repeat

```
save
quit
```

Notice that when removing repositories with submodules one will most probably want to remove those too as they refer to a working copy inside the deleted one.

SCM accounts (as opposed to repositories) can be deleted from menu `Xcode` > `Preferences` > `Accounts` tab.

References:
https://fgimian.github.io/blog/2015/06/27/a-simple-plistbuddy-tutorial/
[Clearing history list of repositories in XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36617471/clearing-history-list-of-repositories-in-xcode)

On a side note, I also noticed a few similar questions on SO:
[How to clear repository checkout history in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35600576/how-to-clear-repository-checkout-history-in-xcode)
[How to remove remote git urls from xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36099035/how-to-remove-remote-git-urls-from-xcode)